# how to remove the "Content Type" field from the Enterprise Wiki page content type

Tags: sharepoint-designer, development, content-type, page-layout, edit-form

I am working on an Enterprise wiki site collection , now when users go to (Page Option >> Edit properties >> Edit Properties) as follow:-

[image]

they will find a field named "Content Type" as follow:-

[image]

so is there a way to remove this drop down list ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your list/library has multiple content types associated with it, the drop down will appear. If there are other content types that are not being used, remove them from the list and they'll go away.

Otherwise, you'll need some script or css to remove/hide it.

Comment: we are 100% correct my library is using the following content types ; Error Page + Enterprise Wiki Page + Redirect Page + Project Page. and i do not want to remove these content types.. so i prefer if i can remove any extra fields from the edit form using css and javascripts but not sure how i can do so ?

Comment: @PiratecEric i wrote the following script inside the Edit form to hide unwanted fields "$('#formTbl tr').filter(function () {
    return !$(".ms-standardheader", this).text().match(/Name|Title/i);
}).remove();" and it was able to hide the extra fields i do not want ,, so my question now if writting such as script is valid approach ?

Comment: If you don't want users to have the ability to switch the content type of the item on the edit form, then yes.

Comment: i want this to apply for the Content type drop down list and on other fields, now if i decide to hide the fields from the content type , this will cause a problem when the users want to compare the Page history for the wiki page. because the hidden fields will not be part of the comparison,, so i found using javascript the more convenient way to achieve my requirement ... and seems that when i chose to hide a field using javascript its value will not be effected..i was affraid if i hide some fields and i edit the web page the hidden fields will be empty..

Comment: @PiratecEric now if i hide some fields from the EditForm using javascript as you propsed, what will happen to the fields that have been hidden ?, will their values be set to null or empty if the user submit the edit form with only specific fields shown ?

Comment: if you hide them, the values in the fields will persist

Comment: @PiratecEric As I am from a .net background where if you submit a form with some values removed from it , the removed fields will be set to null or set to their default value,, but not sure how Sharepoint handle this ?

Comment: don't do a .remove(), do a .hide(), removing them could cause postback or validation problems